# Kafka 1.1.0 keeps getting partition leader epoch

Tags: apache-kafka, upgrade

I have a problem with Kafka.

I upgraded to kafka version from 0.11.0.1 to 1.1.0. After the upgrade, I'm getting the below warn message too much.

```
[2018-06-19 13:34:45,377] WARN Received a PartitionLeaderEpoch assignment for an epoch < latestEpoch. This implies messages have arrived out of order. New: {epoch:0, offset:350280659}, Current: {epoch:4, offset:126401625} for Partition: __consumer_offsets-48 (kafka.server.epoch.LeaderEpochFileCache)
[2018-06-19 13:34:45,386] WARN Received a PartitionLeaderEpoch assignment for an epoch < latestEpoch. This implies messages have arrived out of order. New: {epoch:0, offset:793868383}, Current: {epoch:4, offset:792201264} for Partition: __consumer_offsets-42 (kafka.server.epoch.LeaderEpochFileCache)
[2018-06-19 13:34:45,388] WARN Received a PartitionLeaderEpoch assignment for an epoch < latestEpoch. This implies messages have arrived out of order. New: {epoch:0, offset:793868384}, Current: {epoch:4, offset:792201264} for Partition: __consumer_offsets-42 (kafka.server.epoch.LeaderEpochFileCache)
[2018-06-19 13:34:45,400] WARN Received a PartitionLeaderEpoch assignment for an epoch < latestEpoch. This implies messages have arrived out of order. New: {epoch:0, offset:793868385}, Current: {epoch:4, offset:792201264} for Partition: __consumer_offsets-42 (kafka.server.epoch.LeaderEpochFileCache)
```

How can I resolve this warn messages?

Comment: Make sure NTP is working correctly on all machines and their times are aligned

Comment: Reassign Kafka partitions - https://sleeplessbeastie.eu/2022/01/05/how-to-reassign-kafka-topic-partitions-and-replicas/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reassigned the partitions that issued this kind of warn message. I no longer receive these warn messages. If you are getting like these messages, you can try reassign partitions. It worked for me.