# Kafka big logs issue - don't really know what's going on

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, offset

In my cluster I have 4 `Brokers` hosted on 4 servers; each server hosts a `Kafka Broker` and a `Zookeeper daemon`. The Brokers share this configuration:

```
num of partitions: 8
replication factor: 4
log segment bytes 1,07GB
```

On Server2 and Server4 (*Broker 2 and 4*) logs after 24 hours have size of 18 GB. And this is a problem. In logs we can see these kind of WARN messages, constantly repeated:

```
WARN Received a PartitionLeaderEpoch assignment for an epoch < latestEpoch. 
This implies messages ave arrived out of order. New: {epoch:46, offset:7902727725},
CurrentL {epoch:147, 78884395360} for Partition: topic.

WARN Received a PartitionLeaderEpoch assignment for an epoch < latestEpoch. 
This implies messages ave arrived out of order. New: {epoch:46, offset:7902727726}, 
CurrentL {epoch:147, 78884395360} for Partition: topic.
```

I also noticed that offset is incrementing by each line.

What is the problem here?

**Edit:**
[image]

- partition reassignment unfortunately had no effect
- sorry, maybe my bad: we have 5 zookeeper nodes as it is on the picture but I am not sure if kafka manager always displays only active nodes or all?
- all we have left is update, but I will try it a bit later (can't do it now) and I am going to say about the results

**Edit2:**

- I tried to reassign partitions, it was completed (sometimes status stops on pending only)
  additional screens:
  [image]

[image]

What about settings?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, remove one of the `Zookeeper`s  from your quorum: the number must me **odd** in order to guarantee majority in the decissions to be made:

> A replicated group of servers in the same application is called a
> Quorum. ZooKeeper uses **Majority Quorums, which means that every
> voting requires a majority to vote on**.

Imagine the voting of a new leader: `ZK1` and `ZK2` vote *"Trump"*, while `ZK3` and `ZK4` vote *"Harris"*. The result is a draw: there's no majority, so there's no decission. *Kanye West is elected president*.

The usual number of `Zookeeper` daemons in a cluster is `1,3,5,7`.
For your specific case, **3** should be good.

*Edit after Damianos17's comment: the zk number was 5, not 4. So the text above doesn't affect in the issue; 5 is totally valid, and Kanye should be elected*

---

**Regarding your problem**, it seems to be related to [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7093). The big logs issue is just a consequence of a problem within your Kafka cluster.

As other users [comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7093?focusedCommentId=16642300&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16642300), the error leads to **spamming gigabytes of WARN log messages**, like the ones you posted as example. As a result, **you get those 18GB log files** *that no one with a healthy mind would ever try to read*.

This is because the `assign` operation in the [**`LeaderEpochFileCache`**](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.11/1.0.0/source-code/kafka/server/epoch/LeaderEpochFileCache.scala) class, which  *Assigns the supplied Leader Epoch to the supplied Offset*, will call `validateAndMaybeWarn` if there's an inconsistency within the epochs.

And that method was created with a rampant **hoarding disorder** behaviour. If the validation can't be made, it will log the warning at every call.

```
  def validateAndMaybeWarn(epoch: Int, offset: Long) = 
 {
    //....
   if (epoch < latestEpoch())
     warn(s"Received a PartitionLeaderEpoch assignment for an epoch < latestEpoch."+    
          s"This implies messages have arrived out of order.")
     // Diogenes rules //
    //....
 }
```

On the other hand, and caused by the [**high watermark truncation**](https://rongxinblog.wordpress.com/2016/07/29/kafka-high-watermark/), you could also notice **data loss** on your cluster. *This is just a possibility, and may not happen in your case*.

This [comment from one of Kafka's authors](https://www.mail-archive.com/jira@kafka.apache.org/msg19819.html) affirms that the main error (*the one that leads to the creation of big logs*) should be ***resolved*** in [this update](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7415).

As a workaround, I found some info ([csdn](https://blog.csdn.net/qq_30868737/article/details/110803662), [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50926508/kafka-1-1-0-keeps-getting-partition-leader-epoch)) suggesting that a **partition reassignment** may ***fix*** your problem.

*The text below is copied from a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58202775/2148953) whose author is a jerk*

---

***Partition Reassignment***

You could use Kafka's `kafka-reassign-partitions.sh` to generate the reassignment.

The method, as specified on the [kafka docs](https://www.mail-archive.com/jira@kafka.apache.org/msg19819.html), follows this logic:

1. **Generate Proposed partition reassignment configuration**

First, you should create a json file such as the provided in the link. Let's name it `topics.json`.

```
{
  "topics": [{"topic": "foo1"},
            {"topic": "foo2"}],
  "version":1
}
```

This will tell kafka what are the topics you are willing to rellocate their partitions from. In the example, he wants Kafka to make a proposal for topics `foo1` and `foo2`.

With that json, call the tool and set the active broker list in the command:

```
kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper $ZK_HOSTS 
--topics-to-move-json-file topics.json --broker-list "1,2,3,4,5" --generate
```

This will output Kafka's proposal, which you can save into another .json file. For example:

```
{
  "version":1,
  "partitions":[{"topic":"foo1","partition":2,"replicas":[5,6]},
              {"topic":"foo1","partition":0,"replicas":[5,6]},
              {"topic":"foo2","partition":2,"replicas":[5,6]},
              {"topic":"foo2","partition":0,"replicas":[5,6]},
              {"topic":"foo1","partition":1,"replicas":[5,6]},
              {"topic":"foo2","partition":1,"replicas":[5,6]}]
}
```

You can manually modify some of the assignments, if you want to (or think it's the proper think to do, as the tool is not perfect). Save the json into a file, for example, `reassign-example.json`, which will be used in the next step.

2. **Execute the Proposed partition reassignment**

Let's make Kafka execute the proposal and move the partitions. For that, execute:

```
bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper $ZK_HOSTS 
 --reassignment-json-file reassign-example.json --execute
```

---

**In resume, as a suggestion, I would try to:**

0. *Reduce the number of ZK to 3.*
1. Reassign the partitions.
2. If the previous step doesn't work, update to a `Kafka` version that includes [this update](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7415).

*Be aware that the reassignment may only be a temporal fix and there's a possibility for the issue to happen again in the future.*

Comment: Thank you for your extended response, I appreciate it a lot, nevertheless the problem is still there. I edited my answer a little, because I realized there are 5 zookeeper nodes. I can't stand to the moment when I check if update resolve big logs issue

Comment: Yes, it would as well.

Comment: @Damianos17 sorry to hear the fix didn't work (maybe it does in certain versions,...) On the positive side, the update will effectively solve this. It's a pit, I know...

Comment: I added screens, could you take a peek? Is it saying something? I am also afraid of restarting kafka and zookeeper completely because of complexity of kafka/system

Comment: Hi @Damianos17. That can be one of the cleanest configs I've ever seen: there's no issue within your cluster. On one side, you should be happy; On the other side, this involves you've been hit by the bug, so only a update would really fix the problem

Comment: This can be helpful --> https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#basic_ops_mirror_maker